# uwsgi on heroku gets into failed state - unable to add anything to packet

Tags: python, heroku, uwsgi

Several times in the last few weeks one of my uwsgi-based heroku web dynos has gotten into a failed state, where only a restart fixes things.  Here are the logs I see for almost every request on the dyno once it gets into this state:

```
Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku heroku/router:  at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/heartbeat/" host=mytestsite.com request_id=bd5ff8cf-7c38-4863-bf1a-08b4c6a73a90 fwd="54.0.0.1" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=503 bytes=0  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add REQUEST_METHOD=GET to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add REQUEST_URI=/heartbeat/ to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add PATH_INFO=/heartbeat/ to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add QUERY_STRING= to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1 to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add SCRIPT_NAME= to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add SERVER_NAME=blahblah-2fd4-4b3c-8fbb-32c6e3c1a782 to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add SERVER_PORT=49737 to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add REMOTE_ADDR=10.254.1.80 to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size  

Dec 18 17:44:43 my-heroku app/web.1:  [WARNING] unable to add HTTP_HOST: bla=blah.mysite.com to uwsgi packet, consider increasing buffer size`
```

Here is my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]

#heroku setup: see https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi-docs/blob/master/tutorials/heroku_python.rst
http-socket = :$(PORT)
processes = 5 
master = true
die-on-term = true
harakiri = 20
harakiri-verbose
reload-mercy = 8
max-requests = 2000  

# the below is required by new relic. be sure to monitor your system
# https://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-and-uwsgi
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true

# the module
module = publisher.wsgi
```

Dyno memory usage during this time was around 450MB out of 512 MB.

My questions are: what is this failed state (unable to add anything to packets) a symptom of? What might have happened to cause uWSGI or my heroku dyno to get into this failed state?

Then: What are the fixes? Should I set [`buffer-size`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#buffer-size) to something in the config, and if so, what is the appropriate value for it on a heroku server?

Comment: which uWSGI version are you using ? this seems a bug (instances not recovering from failed state after out of buffer) fixed some month ago

Comment: Thanks, @roberto Looks like its on 2.06. I'll upgrade to 2.08 and let you know if we see this issue again. It sounds hopeful that that should solve the problem.

Comment: Was there ever a solution found to this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @Eli Upgrading resolved the issue for us